# is possible to use JText::_ to change a variable name to all site langs?

Tags: php, joomla, metadata

I am building a php code to fill some metadata taking info from the same site db, this site is in english, french, and spanish. now i need to create 3 sentences in each language and there are some strings i take from the database that needs to be translated. is there a way i can use JText::_ to take the translation from the language files and set it to different variables of each language. ?

i mean something like

```
$var_en = JText::_($cat_name) //store the category name in english
$var_fr = JText::_($cat_name) //store the category name in french
```

how can i specify to JText in my code what language i want to use??

it can be complicated i know, i'll share to you my code for better understanding

```
function createmetadatainfo(){
    global $mtconf;

//USE THIS IF SCRIPT EXECUTION TAKES TOO LONG
//set_time_limit(300);

//USE THE $app OBJECT TO CLOSE THE APPLICATION BEFORE JOOMLA RENDERS THE SITE
$app        = JFactory::getApplication('admin');
    //DATABASE
    global $database;   
    $database       =& JFactory::getDBO();

        //CREATE AND UPDATE METADESC FOR CATEGORIES.
            $query = 'SELECT 
                        `cat_id` , `cat_name` , `cat_links`
                      FROM 
                        `#__mt_cats`
                      ORDER BY 
                        `cat_id`';

            $database->setQuery($query);
            $metaCats = $database->loadAssocList();

            foreach ($metaCats as $value) {
                //building metadescription sentences in different languages. 
                $meta_en = $value['cat_links']." listings on ".$value['cat_name']." category"; 
                $meta_fr = $value['cat_links']." annonces sur ".$value['cat_name']." catégorie";
                $meta_es = $value['cat_links']." listados en la categoría ".$value['cat_name'];
                $cat_id = $value['cat_id'];
                $query_cat_metadesc = "UPDATE `#__mt_cats` SET `metadesc` = '$meta_en' ,
                                                            `metadesc_fr` = '$meta_fr' ,
                                                            `metadesc_es` = '$meta_es'
                                                             WHERE `cat_id` = '$cat_id'";
                $database->setQuery($query_cat_metadesc);
                $database->query();
            }

//CLOSE the $app
$app->close();
```

}

Please notice inside the foreach statement that i need to store inside $meta_en, $meta_fr and $meta_es the variable $value['cat_name'] in diferent languages

Answer (score 0):

The [`JText::_()`](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Language/JText.html#_) call and usage does not offer you any way to change the language. It's for application wide translating, so the application language that is bound per each request is used.

Instead you could consider to create your own [`JLanguage`](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Language/JLanguage.html) objects so you have more control about which language(s) to use.